# Existence of a sequence with prescribed limit and satisfying a certain inequality

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose you have two infinite sequences $\{a_n\}, \{b_n\}$, with $0 < a_n < b_n$ for each $n$, such that $b_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Does there exist a sequence $\{s_n\}$ with $s_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ such that $a_n s_n \geq b_n$ for $n$ large enough? Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes, but not always, even if $a_n>0$

Comment: Could you please explain why? What would be sufficient conditions for $s_n$ to exist? Thanks.

Comment: Consider the limit of $\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}$ if it exists.  In particular if it is $0$, $1$ or $\frac12$

Comment: Thanks Henry. I understand now.

Comment: Henry, please see the related post

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1014713/existence-of-a-sequence-with-prescribed-limit-and-satisfying-a-certain-inequalit

with a more specific and very related question! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO.

If such sequence $s_n$ existed, then we would have that 
$$
\frac{b_n}{a_n}=s_n\to 1.
$$

Take for example
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{n} \quad\text{and}\quad b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}.
$$
Then
$$
\frac{b_n}{a_n}=\frac{1}{n}\to 0,
$$
hence, for this pair of $(a_n)$, $(b_n)$ no such sequence $(s_n)$ exists.

Comment: Thanks. Actually $b_n > a_n$ by assumption but then in this case $b_n/a_n = n$ if $b_n = 1/n$ and $a_n = 1/n^2$ and so no such $s_n$ exists.

Comment: What happens if we force that $a_n \sim b_n$. Please see the new revision of the question here:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1014713/existence-of-a-sequence-with-prescribed-limit-and-satisfying-a-certain-inequalit

Answer (score 0):

As $1<a_n<b_n$, so $\frac{b_n}{a_n}>1$.

If exist such $s_n$, then $s_n\geq\frac{b_n}{a_n}>1$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n=1\Rightarrow\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}=1$.

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}\neq1$, then cannot exist such $s_n$.

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}=1$, then exist $s_n=\frac{b_n}{a_n}$ satisfy the conditions.

Comment: The original post has $0 < a_n < b_n$ but the point still works.