# Existence of a sequence with prescribed limit and satisfying a certain inequality II

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

This is a more specific variation of the question in the post

[Existence of a sequence with prescribed limit and satisfying a certain inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1014662/existence-of-a-sequence-with-prescribed-limit-and-satisfying-a-certain-inequalit)

Suppose you have two infinite sequences $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$, with $0<a_n<b_n < 1$ for each $n$, such that both $a_n, b_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. **Further assume that $a_n/b_n \to 1$** as $n \to \infty$.

Does there exist a sequence $\{s_n\}$ with $s_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ such that 
$$
(1 - a_n) \leq (1-b_n)s_n  
$$ for $n$ large enough?

The counterexamples given in the post above used sequences $a_n, b_n$ which grew asymptotically different (but which had the same limit). This question forces that $a_n \sim b_n$.

Comment: My feeling is that this should be true due to L'Hopital rule?